# Why does the api call not go through in django?

Tags: django, api

This is the url-

```
url(r'^admin/login/$', admin_authentication),
```

The function has post request and accepts-

```
    username = request_body['username']
    password = request_body['password']
```

And the postman has the body in POST format as-

```
{
    "username" : "abcd",
    "password" : "abcd"
}
```

The error is-

```
Page not found at /plugins/admin/login
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the error was sometimes in postman-

127.0.0.1/plugins/admin/login works

but generally, we do this-

127.0.0.1/plugins/admin/login/

The slash at the end is necessary, it may or may not work without it.